# When is the 9-digit number(s) : $abc398246$ divisible by $317$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let  $$N= abc398246=10^6X+398*10^3+246$$
Next, I solved $$[(10^6 X+398246) ~\text{Mod}~~317]=0,~ 100\le X\le 999$$
at the **computer** in the DO-loop $(100-999)$ to get $$abc=X=313,~ 630 ~~and~~947.$$

The question here is: How to do it by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computing $10^6$ and $398246$ modulo $317$ gives $182$ and $94$ respectively, so the equation in $X$ reduces to
$$182X\equiv-94\equiv223\bmod317$$
We now need to find the inverse of $182$, which is $54$; multiplying this with $223$ gives $313$ modulo $317$. The solutions for $X$ are of the form $317k+313$ such that this number is positive and $3$ digits long: $313,630,947$.

All these computations can be reasonably carried out by hand.